# Transform day in year to date

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, date, date-format

How I find which is date in this year if I only know day as number ...

Lets say if I know that day is '1' then to get 01.01.2014, if i know that day is '32' then to get 01.02.2014 ?

Is it possible in javascript?

What about php?

Comment: It's possible in every language that supports date.

Comment: everything is possible.
but you should decide, you want client-side (javascript) or server-side (php) processing of the date ...
see the mktime() function in php ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP way:

```
$first_day_of_this_year = strtotime( date( 'Y-01-01 00:00:00' ) ); //as unix timestamp
$after_32_days = $first_day_of_this_year + 32 * 24 * 60 * 60;
echo date( "Y-m-d", $after_32_days );
```

This will output `2014-02-02`

This will always work for current year. If you want to use it for other year just replace `Y` in first date() function with desired year.

This should work correctly with leap years.

**EDIT:**

I made a function:

```
function day_number_to_date( $day_in_year, $year = null ) {
    $year = ( is_null( $year ) ) ? date("Y") : $year; //use current year if it was not passed to function
    $first_day_of_year = strtotime( date( "$year-01-01 00:00:00" ) ); //first day of year as unix timestamp
    $days_to_add = $day_in_year - 1;
    $target_timestamp = $first_day_of_year + $days_to_add * 24 * 60 * 60;
    $target_date = date( "Y-m-d", $target_timestamp );
    return $target_date;
}
echo day_number_to_date( 32 ); //2014-02-01
echo day_number_to_date( 32, 2020 ); //2020-02-01
echo day_number_to_date( 400 ); //2015-02-04
```

Comment: why this dont work for me - give me wrong date:   $target_date = date( "l, Y-d-m", $target_timestamp );

Comment: @JamesD. It's working for me (outputs `Saturday, 2014-01-02`), except that you switched day with month.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var date = new Date("" + new Date().getFullYear() );
var day = 32;

date.setDate(date.getDate() + day-1);

console.log(date); // => Sat Feb 01 2014 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, you can do this by simply creating a new `Date` object with the days parameter set to the day of the year you require - see the Parameters note section on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

```
var dayInYear = 32;
var newDate = new Date(2014, 0, dayInYear);
// newDate is 01 Feb.
```

or if you have an existing Date object:

```
var theDate = new Date('01/01/2014');
var dayInYear = 32;
var newDate = new Date(theDate.getFullYear(), theDate.getMonth(), dayInYear);
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading your question it sounds like you want to provide day and year to the function to get particular date.

```
function getDateFromDay( year, day) {
     return new Date((new Date(year, 0)).setDate(day));
}

getDateFromDay(2014, 1); // will give Wed Jan 01 2014 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need your code to know what year it is, too -- that pesky 29 Feb every fourth year -- but it's just a matter of successively subtracting the month lengths until the remainder is less than the next month length (while keeping track of which month was last subtracted).  Something like this fragment (pseudo-C):

```
day_to_month (year, day_in_year)
  {
  day_count = day_in_year;
  if (not_leap_year());
    while (day_in_year < month [month_count])
      {
        subtract month[month_count++];
      }
  else
    while (day_in_year < leap_month [month_count])
      {
         subtract leap_month [month_count++];
      }
    }
  date_set (year, month_count, day_count);
```

I don't write javascript, but I know of no reason this couldn't be done even in a bash script -- just requires ability to declare and initialize arrays, and basic arithmetic and flow control functions.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function day2Date( day, year ) {
  return new Date(year,0,day);
}
console.log( day2Date( 32, 2014 ) ); //gives Sat Feb 01 2014 00:00:00
```